# fragment shader to colorize a grayscale texture with alpha channel

Tags: opengl, shader

Solution: Fix the typo (glColor -> gl_Color)

I have a texture with grayscale colors and an alpha channel with either 0f or 1f (nothing in between). I want to draw the texture in green but only when alpha is 1 and draw nothing when alpha is 0. To select green, so I've set glColor4fv green_opaque with GLfloat green_opaque .5 1 .5 1

Now, I use this fragment shader:

```
const char * fragment_shader_source=
        "uniform sampler2D tex;"
        "void main() {"
        "       vec4 color=texture2D(tex,gl_TexCoord[0].st);"
        "       if (color[3]!=0) {"
#ifdef A
        "               gl_FragColor=color*glColor;"
#else
        "               gl_FragColor=color;"
#endif
        "       } else {"
        "               discard;"
        "       }"
        "}"
;
```

Without A, the shader respects the alpha channel but the rendered texture obviously remains gray. Now, I define A and the shader now colorizes the texture as I want, but alpha channel gets ignored now.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it a driver/hardware bug?

OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6570
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11554 Compatibility Profile Context
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20

Answer:

"Do you mean "gl_Color" instead of "glColor" in your shader?"

Exactly that was the problem - which btw I figured out myself yesterday already, but due to java script issues i couldn't post the answer yet.

After adding the underscore, the shader did exactly what it was supposed to do.

Comment: You say that the alpha channel is being ignored. Well, what do you want the alpha channel to *do*?

Comment: Do you mean "gl_Color" instead of "glColor" in your shader?  Any errors or warnings from the GLSL compiler?